# ImpressPages 4.x database where condition with greater or less than

Tags: php, impresspages

How can i use greater or less than in sql where conditions (`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`) on ImpressPages 4.x. I tried something like following but i got error on `ipDb()->update()` and `ipDb()->delete()` functions:

```
ipDb()->delete('Persons', array('age <=' => 18));

ipDb()->delete('Persons', array('age >' => 80));

ipDb()->delete('Persons', array('age <' => 25));

ipDb()->delete('Persons', array('age >=' => 41));
```

**The Error:**

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'age <=' in 'where clause'' in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ipDb() provides you very nice methods to cover 90% of your taks. But they don't cover all 100%. If you need to do the join or anything else more complex, use ipDb()->execute($sql, $paremters). This way you can execute any kind of query.

In your particular case, ImpressPages has sqlMinAge and sqlMaxAge functions that may suit your case http://www.impresspages.org/docs/class-ip-db. If not, use raw SQL and ipDb()->execute method.

Comment: Like this? `ipDb()->execute("UPDATE Persons SET status = 0 WHERE age < = :age", array('age' => $age));` Should i use `execute` the query?

Comment: Yes like this. Isn't it working for you? There are two things I'm concerned:

1 No prefix on table name. Use

$table = ipTable('Persons');

ipDb()->execute("UPDATE $table SE ...

2. I'm not sure  if MySQL supports the space here "< ="

But in general the idea is right. Turn on error reporting if you don't see any error.

Comment: It's working well. I just write as sample. Yes i mistyped, should be `age <= :age`